# Table's Inputs total depend on select option using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the male female to be a separate total in the input box below. But at present both of them come in one input box, I don't know its mechanism. How can I do according to the design?

```js
$(document).on("change", ".track", function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".track").each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  $("#total").val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <table  >
    <tr>
        <select name='type[]'>
          <option value="male"> Male</option>
          <option value="female"> Female</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track" value="" /> <br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <select name='type[]'>
      <option value="female"> Female</option>
      <option value="male"> Male</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track" value="" /> <br>
  </tr>
  </table>  
  
<hr>

<label> Male Total: </label>
<input type="text" id="total" value="" />

<label> Female Total: </label>
<input type="text" id="return" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this example below can help you. It is without using jQuery (but if necessary, it is not difficult to rewrite using jQuery) and uses the `form` tag to catch a form change event:

```js
const types = document.querySelectorAll('select[name="type[]"]');
const amounts = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="amount[]"]');
const totalMale = document.querySelector('#total-male');
const totalFemale = document.querySelector('#total-female');
const form = document.querySelector('#form');

const changeCallback = () => {
  const total = {
    male: 0,
    female: 0
  };
  types.forEach((el, i) => {
    total[el.value] += Number(amounts[i].value) || 0
  });
  totalMale.value = total.male;
  totalFemale.value = total.female;
}

form.addEventListener('change', changeCallback);
changeCallback();
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <select name='type[]'>
        <option value="male"> Male</option>
        <option value="female"> Female</option>
      </select>

      <input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track" value="" /> <br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <select name='type[]'>
        <option value="female"> Female</option>
        <option value="male"> Male</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track" value="" /> <br>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<hr>

<label> Male Total: </label>
<input type="text" id="total-male" value="" />

<label> Female Total: </label>
<input type="text" id="total-female" value="" />
```

If the form tag bothers you, then you can do without it by marking all the elements of the form with one selector (for example, class `.form-element`):

```js
const types = document.querySelectorAll('select[name="type[]"]');
const amounts = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="amount[]"]');
const totalMale = document.querySelector('#total-male');
const totalFemale = document.querySelector('#total-female');
const formElements = document.querySelectorAll('.form-element');

const changeCallback = () => {
  const total = {
    male: 0,
    female: 0
  };
  types.forEach((el, i) => {
    total[el.value] += Number(amounts[i].value) || 0
  });
  totalMale.value = total.male;
  totalFemale.value = total.female;
}

formElements.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('change', changeCallback)
});
changeCallback();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <select name='type[]' class="form-element">
      <option value="male"> Male</option>
      <option value="female"> Female</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track form-element" value="" /> <br>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <select name='type[]' class="form-element">
      <option value="female"> Female</option>
      <option value="male"> Male</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track form-element" value="" /> <br>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr>

<label> Male Total: </label>
<input type="text" id="total-male" value="" />

<label> Female Total: </label>
<input type="text" id="total-female" value="" />
```